# zfs mountpoint not using the dataset

Tags: filesystems, mount, zfs, linuxmint

I am currently building a media server based on Linux Mint. The OS is installed on a small SSD and the intention is to store the media files on two HDDs (2TB + 4TB). To this end I have created a zfs pool called zstorage from the two HDDs. Then I added to this pool a dataset called movies. I have set the mountpoint to /home/gs/movies.

The output from zfs list appears to confirm this was created.

```
gs@Odin:~ > sudo zfs list
NAME              USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zstorage          118K  5.35T    21K  /zstorage
zstorage/movies    21K  5.35T    21K  /home/gs/movies
```

However when I try to copy files to the location /home/gs/movies the space on the SSD is being consumed and the files are not being stored on the HDDs that the zfs pool and dataset have been created.

Can anyone give shed some light on this?

Output from df

```
gs@Odin:~ > df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           788M  1.5M  786M   1% /run
/dev/dm-0       102G   87G  9.7G  90% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G   80K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2       237M   51M  174M  23% /boot
/dev/sda1       511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
zstorage        5.4T   21K  5.4T   1% /zstorage
```

Output from zpool list

```
gs@Odin:~ > sudo zpool status 
pool: zstorage
state: ONLINE
scrub: none requested
config:

NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
zstorage    ONLINE       0     0     0
  sdb       ONLINE       0     0     0
  sdc       ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: Just so you know, you didn't configure any RAID protection across your disks. If one drive fails, you will lose zstorage.

Comment: Thanks @ewwhite, that is a deliberate choice. None of files I will be storing will be critical or couldn't be recovered elsewhere. I prioritised space over the risk of data loss

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue, but the resolution is unsatisfactory. However, I post it here incase it helps anyone else.

It appears that the dataset was never successfully mounted. This is apparent from the df listing. I tried mounting the drive manually using 
    sudo zfs mount -v zstorage/movies

This for reasons I cannot discern took about 5 minutes to complete. There seemed to be no messages in dmesg and I also used the verbose flag (-v) so I could see what was happening, but there were no indications.

After the command had successfully returned. The dataset had mounted to the mountpoint as expected and df shows the mount with the full storage available.

TLDR;

enter command:

```
sudo zfs mount -av
```

wait for a long time for it to complete